# jQuery validation plugin problem when served by JSP using @include

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Greetings!

I'm trying to combine several JS files into one and serve it through JSP but I'm running into a problem with the jquery validation plugin 1.6

The JSP aggregating various `.js` files:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/javascript" pageEncoding="UTF-8"  %>

<c:if test="${jquery}">
    <%@include file="/js/jQuery/jquery-1.4.x.js" %>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${navMenu}">
    <%@include file="/js/verticalNavMenu.js.jsp" %>
</c:if>

<c:if test="${validate}">
    <%@include file="/js/jQuery/jquery.validate.js" %>
</c:if>
```

I've tested including the jQuery file and the custom `verticalNavMenu` file and all's fine

Including `jquery.validate.js` breaks the whole thing.

Here's the kicker though, if don't aggregate the validation plugin in the JSP file, but call it in the file that requires it ( `form.jsp` for example ) all work like a charm.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what, "breaks the whole thing" means. Do you get JSP errors (like, on the server)?  Errors from the browser? What exactly are the errors? What exactly does the amalgamated Javascript file look like?

Comment: validation does not work
no server errors
the file looks like all the other copied an pasted, one under another separated by cr

FireBug says:

jQuery is not defined
http://localhost:8084/mysite/js/jQuery/jquery.validate.js
Line 2

invalid quantifier ?\{(\d+)\}
http://localhost:8084/mysite/js/dynamic/dynamic_combo_js.js?jquery=true&navMenu=true&validate=true&
Line 275


$("#feedback").validate is not a function
http://localhost:8084/mysite/js/sections/information/feedback.js
Line 34

Comment: If it were me, I'd be looking for syntax problems with that "verticalNavMenu.js.jsp" file, things like missing parenthesis, dangling commas, etc.

Comment: ... tried that, still does not work when verticalNavmenu is eliminated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you probably have something in one of those files that causes a syntax error in the JS when something else goes before or after it. You should look at the file and see what that is.

try putting

;

between the files, that might help. I cant help more without seeing the concatted file

Answer (score 2):

The code looks fine. As per the comments ("jQuery is not defined"), the only cause for this problem would be that you included the jQuery validation file **without** including the jQuery core file itself. Thus, when `${validate}` evaluates `true`, you should ensure that `${jquery}` also evaluates `true`. You can also do that in the `c:if` block:

```
<c:if test="${jquery || validate}">
    <%@include file="/js/jQuery/jquery-1.4.x.js" %>
</c:if>
```